# How to NOT create a view and session file when viewing man pages

Tags: vimscript, neovim, sessions, pager

I recently discovered the world of vim session files, and they are awesome for working with multi-file code projects.

However, when opening a `man` page I don't need a session file created for viewing man pages.

I like using Neovim to view man pages because of the color and trackpad support when reading a man page.

I recently cobbled the below together to view man pages using a function called `vman`

```
function vman --description 'use vim / nvim to read man pages'
  man $argv | col -bp | iconv -c | nvim 'set ft=man nomod nolist' -;
end
```

However, when I invoke, `nvim` it loads the below `session.vim` file from `$HOME/.vim/plugin` directory

```
" CREDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656092/708807

function! MakeSession(overwrite)
  let b:sessiondir = $HOME . "/.vim/sessions" . getcwd()
  if (filewritable(b:sessiondir) != 2)
    exe 'silent !mkdir -p ' b:sessiondir
    redraw!
  endif
  let b:filename = b:sessiondir . '/session.vim'
  if a:overwrite == 0 && !empty(glob(b:filename))
    return
  endif
  exe "mksession! " . b:filename
endfunction

function! LoadSession()
  let b:sessiondir = $HOME . "/.vim/sessions" . getcwd()
  let b:sessionfile = b:sessiondir . "/session.vim"
  if (filereadable(b:sessionfile))
    exe 'source ' b:sessionfile
  else
    echo "No session loaded."
  endif
endfunction

" Adding automatons for when entering or leaving Vim
if(argc() == 0)
  au VimEnter * nested :call LoadSession()
  au VimLeave * :call MakeSession(1)
else
  au VimLeave * :call MakeSession(0)
endif
```

Is there some a way I can check to see if the buffer is loading a `.man` file and not create a session file?

---

Per Rich's answer, I ended up modifying the above posted `sessions.vim` file to the below,

**" sessions.vim**

```
" CREDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656092/708807

    function! MakeSession(overwrite)
      if &filetype ==? 'man'
        return
      else
        let b:sessiondir = $HOME . "/.vim/sessions" . getcwd()
        if (filewritable(b:sessiondir) != 2)
          exe 'silent !mkdir -p ' b:sessiondir
          redraw!
        endif
        let b:filename = b:sessiondir . '/session.vim'
        if a:overwrite == 0 && !empty(glob(b:filename))
          return
        endif
        exe "mksession! " . b:filename
      endif
    endfunction

    function! LoadSession()
      if &filetype ==? 'man'
        return
      else
        let b:sessiondir = $HOME . "/.vim/sessions" . getcwd()
        let b:sessionfile = b:sessiondir . "/session.vim"
        if (filereadable(b:sessionfile))
          exe 'source ' b:sessionfile
        else
          echo "No session loaded."
        endif
      endif
    endfunction

    " Adding automatons for when entering or leaving Vim
    if(argc() == 0)
      au VimEnter * nested :call LoadSession()
      au VimLeave * :call MakeSession(1)
    else
      au VimLeave * :call MakeSession(0)
    endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you don't open lots of other files inside the instance of Vim that you're using to view man pages, you can achieve this by checking the file type of the current buffer before saving the session:

```
function! MakeSession(overwrite)
  if &filetype ==? 'man'
    return
  endif

  " The rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thanks for   steering me in the right direction.    I ended up modifying my `sessions.vim` a little different from what you posted above.

And btw, is there no syntax highlighting for Vim script?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought the guard would be necessary in the `LoadSession()` function since you're already checking `argc()` before calling it? As for syntax highlighting of Vimscript, if you're asking about in Vim, the answer is yes. If you mean on this site, then the answer is no. :(

Comment: yeah I meant on this site.  ‍♀️